Godot 4.2.2 Stable: Cannot call method 'warp_mouse' on a null value
In my script that makes it when you collide w/ a area2D, the mouses position gets set back to (0, 0). But I keep getting the error:

Cannot call method ‘warp_mouse’ on a null value.

const set = Vector2(-20, -20)

func _on_area_entered(area):
    get_tree().reload_current_scene()
    get_viewport().warp_mouse(set)

I have no clue what else to try, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Is it possible to move the get_viewport() call to the _ready() method so it's not called until after the scene has been reloaded completely? In my brief testing that seems to fix it. I suspect reload starts a whole new scene and since you're still calling it from the old scene, there's no tree/viewport to call.

The error is specifically because get_viewport() is returning None (python’s version of null), and you cannot invoke a method on None.
Remember, reload_current_scene() invokes a deferred action. You should check the Error result of the function, but even if it returns @GlobalScope.OK the actual reloading is not finished when the function returns.
Hence, ZapTap’s analysis is correct: you should be warping the mouse when the _ready() callback is invoked by Godot Engine.
You can peruse some source code here where someone else asked about it.
